# Posting form data as Json using Knockout JS/ JQuery

Tags: json, jquery, knockout.js

While I try to post the form data in Json format to the server I'm running to some error. My code is as follows.

```
permissionRequestModel.requestPermission = function () {
if ($("#permissionRequestForm").valid()) {
  $.ajax({
          url: "",
          type: "POST",
          data: ko.toJSON(this),
          processData:false,
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType:"json",
          success: function (result) {
                    alert("Success");
                     },
         error: function (result) {
             alert(result.responseText);
                 }
           });
          }
    else {
        }
        };
```

knockout model is as follows

```
//Model
var permissionRequestModel = {
coNumber: ko.observable(''),
employName: ko.observable(''),
fromDate: ko.observable(''),
toDate: ko.observable(''),
checkFullDay: ko.observable(false),
fromTimeHH: ko.observable(''),
fromTimeMM: ko.observable(''),
toTimeHH: ko.observable(''),
toTimeMM: ko.observable(''),
permissionTypeOne: ko.observable(''),
permissionTypeTwo: ko.observable(''),
approverList: ko.observableArray([]),
reasonLeave: ko.observable('')
};
```

Read in some places that it might be because Json might be encoded before sending to server but even setting processData couldnt solve it. Please guide.

Error Message

Comment: Can you share with us the error what you get?

Comment: assuming the whitespace in the url is just a typo, what does `data` look like after `ko.toJSON`?  Do you have any unescaped quotation marks in your JSON?  Also, echoing @nemesv, what is the error you get from the error callback?

Comment: Url whitespace was a typo, have edited the question to include the error message. Thanks.

Comment: @nemesv I do not have access to the server side code right now, but I have found out the error is because approverList:ko.observable([]) is passing null as its value. When a value is given there it works fine. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @nemesv could you help removing the above comment as it contains some sensitive names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `this` to `permissionRequestModel` ... your `this` is not the model because you are no longer in the context of the model.  You are inside a function, and the `this` will return the function.

```
permissionRequestModel.requestPermission = function () {
if ($("#permissionRequestForm").valid()) {
  $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: "POST",
          data: ko.toJSON(permissionRequestModel),
          processData:false,
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType:"json",
          success: function (result) {
                    alert("Success");
                     },
         error: function (result) {
             alert(result.responseText);
                 }
           });
          }
    else {
        }
        };
```

Comment: could you please help me remove/redact this answer as it conatins some sensitive information.